# Does anyone know the origin of the Buddhist Prayer of Forgiveness?

Tags: reference-request, prayer

> **Buddhist Prayer of Forgiveness**
>
> If I have harmed anyone in any way either knowingly or unknowingly
>   through my own confusions I ask their forgiveness.
>
> If anyone has harmed me in any way either knowingly or unknowingly
>   through their own confusions I forgive them.
>
> And if there is a situation I am not yet ready to forgive
>   I forgive myself for that.
>
> For all the ways that I harm myself, negate, doubt, belittle myself,
>   judge or be unkind to myself through my own confusions
>   I forgive myself.

I love this prayer. It is found on many sites on the Internet as the Buddhist Prayer of Forgiveness. Can someone guide me to the origin i.e the sutta where this prayer can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Google search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=If+I+have+harmed+anyone+in+any+way+either+knowingly+or+unknowingly+through+my+own+confusions+I+ask+their+forgiveness&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A2001&tbm=) the first appearances of this text on the internet is in 2001.

And (among those earliest references) [this says](http://www.awakenedliving.com/podcasts/ForgivenessPrayer.pdf),

> Actually, the origins of this prayer are unknown. Sylvia Boorstein shared with me that she learned a prayer almost exactly like this one—a Jewish prayer—as a child.

---

I think that may be right -- it seems to me similar in structure to the [Serenity Prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_Prayer), for example.

---

Also I think that "forgiveness" doesn't show up as a major theme in the Pali canon (but it's central to Christianity, e.g. "the forgiveness of sin"). [This search](https://accesstoinsight.org/search_results.html?cx=006639875531220445029%3A2z3mhfokk-u&ie=UTF-8&q=forgive&sa=Search) doesn't return many results.

[Reconciliation, Right & Wrong](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/reconciliation.html) explains a difference between forgiveness and reconciliation -- to the extent that they do talk about reconciliation, I think that's mostly in a monastic (community) context, and along the line of confessing one's own transgression and admitting a fault, to avoid repeating the mistake: and I think you'd do that in person i.e. say it to someone else, not say it silently in prayer.

The other side of the coin that *is* promoted in the sutta is the [Akkosa Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn07/sn07.002.than.html), where an insult isn't forgiven because it isn't accepted.

And Wikipedia's article about [Forgiveness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgiveness#Buddhism) (which talks about "reliious views" of forgiveness, starting with Judaism) says,

> Buddhism places much emphasis on the concepts of Mettā (loving kindness), karuna (compassion), mudita (sympathetic joy), and upekkhā (equanimity), as a means to avoiding resentments in the first place.

---

The one kind of Buddhist text that this does remind me of is the [Metta Gatha](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13883/254).

By Googling for *khama gatha* I found some slighty similar texts, for example in this [Gatha Book](http://www.sibv.org/images/sibv-gatha-book.pdf):

> ASKING FOR FORGIVENESS ( KHAMA YACANA)
>
> Kayena vaca-cittena Pamadena maya katam
>   Accayam khama me bhante Bhuripanna tathagata.
>
> If, due to neglence, I have done some wrong by body,speech, or mind
>   Forgive me of that offence, O Bhante, Perfect One of vast wisdom.

... and these [Daily Buddhist Prayers](http://buddhist-practice.blogspot.fr/2009/03/daily-buddhist-prayers-1.html):

> Rectification of faults
>
> Kāyena vācā cittena
>   Pamādena mayā katam
>   Accayam khama me bhante
>   Bhuri pañña Tathāgata
>
> Kāyena vācā cittena
>   Pamādena mayā katam
>   Accayam khama me dhamma
>   Sanditthika akalika
>
> Kāyena vācā cittena
>   Pamādena mayā katam
>   Accayam khama me Sangha
>   Supatipanna anuttara
>   Sadhu! Sadhu! Sadhu!
>
> If due to negligence I have done
>   Some wrong by body, speech, or mind.
>   Pardon me that offence, Bhante!
>   Perfect One of vast wisdom.
>
> If due to negligence I have done
>   Some wrong by body, speech, or mind.
>   Pardon me that offence, O Dhamma
>   Visible and immediately effective.
>
> If due to negligence I have done
>   Some wrong by body, speech, or mind.
>   Pardon me that offence, O Sangha
>   Practising well and supreme.
>   Excellent! Excellent! Excellent!

Comment: The "kayena vaca" verse starts very similarly to [this Hindu Sanskrit verse](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8978/4596). In fact, the next word "citta" in Pali and "manas" in Sanskrit mean almost the same thing. This leads me to think that this verse was adapted from Hinduism.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no prayers for Forgiveness: we should know about good and bad, we should try to do good and avoid the bad.

Instead of, "If I have harmed anyone in any way either knowingly or unknowingly", it would be better to apologise and remember your fault and don't do it again, and try to follow 5 rules.