# Metta meditation ever taught to householders?

Tags: brahmavihara

Are there references that the Buddha taught such as metta-meditation to householders (wordlings, without complete Sila), giving ground for hypocritical practice, agree with such, in manners of: "There is the case where a householder..."?

Didn't he not focused on getting right view and Silas first?

Was modern householder-metta-meditation ever taught, even trained by the elders, such as doing it inbetween business as usual?

*[Note: this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks and to maintain houses but for liberation and with non-hypocratical metta: may all beings give causes to find there way out for themselves with ease.]*

Comment: "Pannawanthassayan Dhammo, Nayan Dhammo Duppannassa." - This Dhamma has been preached for those who are wise enough to understand in order end this suffering. So there's no division as householders, lay practitioners, monks, etc... All these are suffering from eleven types of fire.

Comment: @Damith [Anuruddhamahāvitakkasutta](https://suttacentral.net/an8.30/en/sujato)

Comment: Not so, housholder, two or onefold. Housholder has not only an outwardly meaning. What is a householder: one who still holds on the six sense objects, and gives into it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one about householders and the four pleasant mental abidings. But I think this refers to the four rupa jhanas rather than the four brahmaviharas.

From [Gihi Sutta (AN 5.179)](https://suttacentral.net/an5.179/en/thanissaro):

> Then Anathapindika the householder, surrounded by about 500 lay
>   followers, went to the Blessed One and, on arrival, having bowed down
>   to him, sat to one side. So the Blessed One said to Ven. Sariputta:
>   “Sariputta, when you know of a householder clothed in white, that he
>   is restrained in terms of the five training rules and that he obtains
>   at will, without difficulty, without hardship, **four pleasant mental
>   abidings** in the here & now, then if he wants he may state about
>   himself: ‘Hell is ended; animal wombs are ended; the state of the
>   hungry shades is ended; states of deprivation, destitution, the bad
>   bourns are ended! I am a stream-winner, steadfast, never again
>   destined for states of woe, headed for self-awakening!’

Not metta specifically but I can find a sutta where the Buddha recommended some lay people to allocate some time to practice jhana meditation.

From the [Piti Sutta (AN 5.176)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.176.than.html):

> Then Anathapindika the householder, surrounded by about 500 lay
>   followers, went to the Blessed One and, on arrival, having bowed down
>   to him, sat to one side. As he was sitting there the Blessed One said
>   to him, “Householder, you have provided the community of monks with
>   robes, alms food, lodgings, & medicinal requisites for the sick, but
>   you shouldn’t rest content with the thought, ‘We have provided the
>   community of monks with robes, alms food, lodgings, & medicinal
>   requisites for the sick.’ So you should train yourself, ‘Let’s
>   periodically enter & remain in seclusion & rapture.’ That’s how you
>   should train yourself.”

Comment: "provided the community of monks with robes, alms food, lodgings, & medicinal requisites for the sick." :-) or even paid a householders medi-center... it points to the six anussatis, btw. Only if things are rightous gained, one is not in debts, ones wealth can be enjoyed.